# MongoDB Monk $push to an array in an object in an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hello all: I am trying to $push a string to an array in an object in an array. I have been fiddling with my NodeJS code for hours but can not figure this out. Below is an example of the data I am working with.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5890c87051e301f17d9ba814"),
    "comments" : [
            {
                    "5890db366a29d63612e1f8f5" : {
                            "eventName" : "111",
                            "startDateTime" : ISODate("2017-01-31T18:50:00Z")
                    }
            }
    ]
```

}

I would like to push to an array called "array" that will appear right under startDateTime.

I am currently trying something like this:

```
$push: { ['comments.' + ObjectID(rateReviewObject.eventID) + '.array'] : rateReviewObject.comment }
```

> MongoError: cannot use the part (comments of comments.5890db366a29d63612e1f8f5.array) to traverse the element ({comments: [ { 5890db366a29d63612e1f8f5: { eventName: "111", startDateTime: new Date(1485888600000) } } ]})

Can anyone help me out?

**EDIT**
Full query:

```
// add the optional review (comment) to the instructor's list of comments in the DB
        commentCollection.update(
          { _id : ObjectID(rateReviewObject.instructorID) },
          {
            $addToSet:
            { 
              comments: 
              {
                eventID: ObjectID(rateReviewObject.eventID),
                eventName: rateReviewObject.eventName,
                startDateTime: new Date(rateReviewObject.startDateTime)
              }
            },
            $push: { ['comments.' + ObjectID(rateReviewObject.eventID) + '.array'] : rateReviewObject.comment }
          },
          { upsert: true }, // create a new document for the instructor if this is their first review
```

Comment: your comment id i.e 5890db366a29d63612e1f8f5 is unique ?

Comment: Yes. It is unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use positional $ operator which returns the index of first matching item from array in combination with $exists operator which checks if a key exists or not in the document. 
Your case it will :

```
db.collection.update({
 "_id" : ObjectId("5890c87051e301f17d9ba814"),
"comments.5890db366a29d63612e1f8f5":{$exists:true}
},{
$push:{
"comments.$.array":rateReviewObject.comment
}
})
```

for more
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

Comment: What if it doesn't exist. What if the is the first time being added to the comments array. I am using {upsert: true}. Please see my edit.

Comment: in that case you can use $setOnInsert Operator.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about $setOnInsert